# Functional Differences or Restrictions on Sharepoint Educational and Standart Licenses

Tags: licensing

we'll be purchasing Sharepoint Server 2010 Educational Licenses for an educational website of a school.

here is the licenses in the offer

*SharePointIntrntSitesStd 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc Qlfd
*SharePointSvr 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc 
*SharePointEntCAL 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc UsrCAL 
*SharePointStdCAL 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc UsrCAL

I Wonder if i would be able to do anything i can do with sharepoint server standart or enterprise edition.Is there any functional restrictions(some services may be not working?)
We may be using mostly a publishing site type on purpose and i guess we won't need extra functions like workflows,office web apps etc. But if we could use office web apps,it would be nice to implement it to school too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For publishing site (**SharePoint Standard**) you need:

1. SharePointSvr 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc
   (for each server in your farm)
2. SharePointStdCAL 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc UsrCAL (for each employee in your organization)

To enable enterprise functionalities you will have to purchase additional Enterprise CALs for employees using these functionalities (e.g. Excel Servies, PerformancePoint Services...) [Check differences between SharePoint editions here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx).

In case you decide to go for **Enterprise** you would have to purchase the following:

1. SharePointSvr 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc
   (for each server in your farm)
2. SharePointStdCAL 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc UsrCAL (for each employee in your organization)
3. SharePointEntCAL 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc UsrCAL (for each employee that is using ENT functionalities)

The one remaining license **SharePointIntrntSitesStd 2010 SNGL OLP NL Acdmc Qlfd** is used if you plan to publish SharePoint publicly for Internet sites.